# Factory_bot, how to reuse parent factory in relationship where child belongs to both parent and parents parent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, factory-bot

`Shift belongs_to` both `Employee` and `Site` while `Employee belongs_to Site`

Given that, here is a factory:

```
  factory :site do
    ...
  end
  
  factory :employee do
    site
    ...
  end

  factory :shift do
    employee # creates a site
    site # creates a new site; i.e., this is NOT same site as employee site, each call creates a new site
    ...
  end
```

When I run `create(:shift)`, I'd like the default created `shift.site` to be the same as the `shift.employee.site`, but currently the behavior is that 2 sites are created, when I only want one.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the already defined fields in Factory Bot. So this works,

```
  factory :site do
    ...
  end
  
  factory :employee do
    site
    ...
  end

  factory :shift do
    employee # creates a site
    site { employee.site }
    ...
  end
```

Comment: that worked, but question, it created a different error where now if I run `create(:shift, employee_id: @employee.id)`, rather than overriding the `employee` from factory, it again creates a new employee id and now I'm once again redundant. I tried to set in the `:shift` factory that `employee_id { employee.id }` but then getting a `NoMethodError` on the `employee` (which makes sense, nothing has called for its creation)

Comment: Can you try with `create(:shift, employee: @employee)`